# When I load a table as pandas data frame, leading zeros in a column disappears. How avoid that

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a table as shown below.

```
id             name
010014         messi
092754         ronaldo
864287         benzema
K26541         xavi
```

When I load above table as pandas data frame, the leading zeros in the `id` column disappears. How can I avoid that.

Data after loading the table as pandas data frame

```
id             name
10014          messi
92754          ronaldo
864287         benzema
K26541         xavi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approache would be to set the `dtype` for your column to `str`:

```
df = pd.read_table(yourdata, dtype = {'id': str})
```

This will also work for [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) or [`pandas.read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)